# Syntax for variable class name (or within a v-if)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a loop and I'm creating many different buttons. In my data property, I have boolean values that I want to use to control whether to display an icon or a spinning loader.

I was thinking of using either a v-if or bind a class so that I apply css. I know the `v-if` and `:class` below are incorrect but I just want to show the 2 different approaches I have so far. What is the correct syntax for either of the approaches?

```
<button
  v-for="action in actionTypes"
    <div
      class="btn btn-shell-grey">
      <component
        :is="`icon-${ action }`"
        v-if="[`${ action }LoadingComplete`]"
        :class="{ hidden: ![ action + 'LoadingComplete']}>
      </component>
      <icon-spin
        v-if="![`${ action }LoadingComplete`]"
        :class="{ hidden: ![ action + 'LoadingComplete']}>
      </icon-spin>
    </div>
  </button>


data(){
  return {
    saveLoadingComplete: true,
    uploadLoadingComplete: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close to having the correct syntax in the snippet you've provided.

To access your data via a dynamically constructed property name in your HTML, use [`$data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data), which proxies access to the data, like so:

```
v-if="$data[`${action}LoadingComplete`]"
```

[And here's a basic working example of this in action.](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4OMEX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I never had the need to use css to hide components in vue. I Always use conditional renders(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show). In your case it should look something like this.

```
<button
  v-for="action in actionTypes"
    <div
      class="btn btn-shell-grey">
      <component
        :is="`icon-${ action }`"
        v-if="action.loadingComplete"
      </component>
      <icon-spin
        v-if="!action.loadingComplete"
      </icon-spin>
    </div>
  </button>
```